# PHP parse_str outputs invalid characters

Tags: php, json, string, parsing

I've noticed the following behaviour of `parse_str`.

I have a string of url params which is for example:

```
"cat=sphd&bpmin=100&bpmax=500&xf=1229_Nackenb%FCgel%7E1231_Bluetooth%7E1999_Sony"
```

If I do `parse_str`, the last param containing invalid character looks like this:

```
        [params] => Array
            (
                [cat] => sphd
                [bpmin] => 100
                [bpmax] => 500
                [xf] => 1229_Nackenb�gel~1231_Bluetooth~1999_Sony
```

Which basically fails to `json_encode`: I need it for caching (under framework).

Question: how to `json_encode` such array with such characters or how to correct such `parse_str` output to actually do `json_encode`?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not parse_str’s “fault”, you simply have the data in your URL encoded in some ISO-8859-x encoding, instead of UTF-8 as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The URL-encoded value `%FC` expresses the *byte* `FC`, which interpreted in ISO-8859-1 is "ü". `json_encode` expects UTF-8 encoded characters though, and apparently so do you, that's why this character doesn't display correctly and `json_encode` rejects it.

If you can change where that URL comes form, URL-encode the *UTF-8 encoded character* so you get `%C3%BC`. If you can't fix it there, you need to convert the parsed strings from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, using [`iconv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), [`mb_convert_encoding`](https://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) or, dare I say, [`utf8_encode`](https://php.net/utf8_encode) (which is almost never appropriate but is here for once).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I suspected this, but after some playing around I didn't come to solution. Unfortunately I cannot change url, it is received via API (and stored in local app db), I need to preserve parsed url params to reconstruct url later. So basically in this case I need encoding from ISO and back to ISO. ...For this case it was easier for me to do a workaround: to modify general selection function to not to select urls from db, in this particular case I needed to cache other than url stuff.